# How can I use a file system like Amazon S3 in combination with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have found many references on the internet on storing media and found recommended to use an S3 bucket to store files with references stored in a database, however I have not found any tutorial on how to do just that.

- I have a unity application where I record/play audio that you can share with other users.
- I want to retrieve/store these files in S3
- I want to have file references of these files in Postgresql

If anyone could show me where I can get started with doing this that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you used Amazon S3 to programmatically store and access files? If you are familiar with Java then try this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3.html You can then apply the logic to your application.

Comment: I'm looking more specifically for information on how to link the Amazon S3 to my postgresql database.

Comment: Once you know how to programmatically access S3 files, you can save the bucket name, region, and key to PostgreSQL or any other database for future access.